# Recommendations to Improve a 3D vector-based class

Tags: c++, visual-c++

The code is otherwise working but I think I lack some more things to implement, I just don't know what exactly to implement. Some recommendations please.

Probably efficacy?

Made the following implementations:

//Functions

> Resize resize()
>   Assign assign()
>   Access access()
>   Move move()
>   Find get_pos()
>   Copy to 2D vector copy()
>   Copy to 1D vector copy()

//Operators

> Insert <<
>   Extract >>
>   Equate =

//matrix.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
#include "dimensional_size.h"
using namespace std;
#define _MATRIX_H_

template<typename type, size_t _breadth = 0, size_t _height = 0, size_t _width = 0>
class matrix {
public:
    matrix();
    ~matrix();
    void resize(size_t new_breadth, size_t new_height = 0, size_t new_width = 0);
    void assign(type obj, pos z, pos y, pos x);
    type access(pos z=0, pos y = 0, pos x = 0);
    void move(dimensional_pos<type> old_pos, dimensional_pos<type> new_pos);
    size_t get_capacity();
    vector<vector<type> >& copy(vector<vector<type> > dest, pos z = 0, pos y = 0, pos dest_z = 0);
    vector<type>& copy(vector<type> dest, pos z = 0, pos y = 0);
    dimensional_pos<type> get_loc(type& t);
    void operator<<(type t);
    void operator>>(type t);
    matrix<type, _breadth, _width, _height> operator=(matrix<type, _breadth, _height, _width> obj);
private:
    dimensional_size<_breadth, _height, _width> size_obj;
    vector<vector<vector<type> > > dat;
};
```

//dimensional_size.h

dimensional_size.h provides data structure "dimensional_size" and class "dimensional_pos" with type definition of "pos" as an unsigned long long integer

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <vector>
#define _DIMENSIONAL_SIZE_H_ 
using namespace std;

template<size_t z, size_t y, size_t x>
struct dimensional_size {
    dimensional_size();
    ~dimensional_size();
    size_t get_capacity();
    size_t get_breadth();
    size_t get_height();
    size_t get_width();
    void up_size(size_t z = 0, size_t y = 0, size_t x = 0);
private:
    size_t absolute_x;
    size_t absolute_y;
    size_t absolute_z;
};

template<typename type>
class dimensional_pos {
public:
    dimensional_pos();
    dimensional_pos(pos z = 0, pos y = 0, pos x = 0);
    ~dimensional_pos();
    dimensional_pos& get_pos(vector<type> stream, type& t);
    dimensional_pos& get_pos(vector<vector<type> > stream, type& t);
    dimensional_pos& get_pos(vector<vector<vector<type> > > stream, type& t);
    pos get_z();
    pos get_y();
    pos get_z();
private:
    pos absolute_x;
    pos absolute_y;
    pos absolute_z;
};
```

Sample style of scaling through a vector to find an object of a type

```
template<typename type>
dimensional_pos<type>& dimensional_pos<type>::get_pos(vector<vector<vector<type> > > stream, type& t) {
    dimensional_pos<type> obj;
    for (pos i = 0; i < stream.size(); i++) {
        for (pos j = 0; j < stream[i].size(); j++) {
            for (pos k = 0; k < stream[i][j].size(); k++) {
                if (t == stream[i][j][k]) {
                    obj(i, j, k);
                    return obj;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

No errors whatsoever.

Comment: This question should be better posted at [SE Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) (supposed your code already works as intended).

Comment: Ask your class users what they want and if it's nothing move on to another project? :P

Comment: I wouldn't use separate types for `dimensional_pos` and `dimensional_size`. You could use a single class (`vec3` is a common name).

Comment: If you don't need to implement anything else then don't!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit i first thought that the question is opinion-based, but then your comment is the correct answer

Comment: @rAndom69 I don't have any users yet so I can't really ask anyone yet

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I only separated them so I won't be confused with their purpose. '''dimensional_pos''' is for positions in a dimensional space and '''dimensional_size''' is for the size... I'll try to implement an unified class for them. Thank you~